# Why SARIMA gives error when predicting negative growth?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, data-science, arima

I am working on SARIMA model and whenever it sees trend reaching to 0. It stops and gives me error.

q has a data.

my_order = (0,1,0)
    my_seasonal_order = (1, 1, 1, 12)

```
model = SARIMAX(q, order=my_order, seasonal_order=my_seasonal_order)
start_params = [0, 0, 1.]
results = model.fit(start_params)
#model_fit = model.fit()

yhat = results.forecast(steps=24).reset_index()
```

What to add in the code STOP whenever the trend is near 0. So that it won't gives me anymore errors.

Comment: Did you decompose the time series or you are applying SARIMA to raw data ?

Comment: More details about the error would also be helpful.

Comment: @Rubens_Z there are different but one of these are,
LinAlgError: Non-positive-definite forecast error covariance matrix encountered at period 18

Comment: Check if you have dtype float or missing values. GitHub link: https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/5374